# AddThis displaying Maintenance screen for email sharing

Tags: addthis

The Email sharing screen on AddThis is displaying "maintenance" screen. It has been displaying this for some time.

**Is there a way to remove this maintenance page and instead have the email client open automatically when the user clicks on the email button?**

Or if there is any alternative please suggest.

[image]

Comment: is this working now? or you have found any solution of this? i have suffering with same issue

Comment: @UttamPanara Still showing the same screen, didn't find any solution.

Comment: I've had this "planned maintenance" message for months now. It looks very unprofessional.

Comment: @UttamPanara There is now a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reached out to AddThis support and here's the response I got.
Sorry everyone.

Thanks for contacting AddThis Support:)

Currently we don’t have any workaround for this .we will update you accordingly.

We’ve received lot of phishing reports recently that users were using our open form email share functionality to send spam emails. In an effort to prevent security issues we’ll be deprecating our open form email share functionality in favor of a more secure email app experience by 1/11/21.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for understanding!

Comment: Thanks for you response, even I contact with the AddThis support team and got the same email.

Comment: still same in june 21

Comment: @TirthPatel there is now a solution.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is caused by the `Share Via Email` option being deprecated.
There is an alternative also provided by AddThis, which is `Share Via Email App`.

In order to fix this, please follow the below steps:

1. Log into your [AddThis Dashboard](https://www.addthis.com/dashboard)
2. Navigate to `Tools` > `Website Tools`.

   - You should see an enabled share button.
   - If you see more than one enabled share buttons, you need to repeat this proess with all the share buttons.
3. In front of the chosen share button, click `Settings`.
4. Under sharing services, make sure that the option `Selected by You` is chosen.
5. Under `Sharing Services`, if you find `Email`, remove it by clicking `X` in front of it.
6. Click `Add more Services`. A list of services is displayed, sorted alphabetically.

   - Select `Email App`.
   - Click the `Update Tool` button.

[image: The Sharing Services page]

*Note that I took this answer from a [post on WebMarked.net](https://www.webmarked.net/fix-email-sharing-with-addthis/), also sorry for the necro-post but I figured since this is the first page to appear on google when searching for this problem, it would be relevant to have an actual solution now that one is available*.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. I'd prefer the email form, but this is much, much better than the maintenance message.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you are using a custom button with the "addthis_button_email" class - you can instead use the "addthis_button_mailto" class. This basically turns the button into a mailto link.